# Implicit transmute when using dplyr arrange in an R function

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

When using the arrange verb in a function that takes the variables to arrange a dataset by as inputs, the function returns error "! Problem with the implicit `transmute()` step". This error does not occur when only one variable is used, however it does occur when multiple variables are used.

Here is the function using the mtcars dataset attempting to sort by one and multiple variables.

```
sort_func <- function(data, by_vars){
  vars <- quo({{by_vars}})
  xpr <- rlang::get_expr(vars)
  
  ds <- data %>% arrange(eval(xpr))
  return(ds)
}

sort_func(data = mtcars, by_vars = as.vector(hp)) ## Returns the data arranged by hp 

sort_func(data = mtcars, by_vars = as.vector(desc(cyl)) ## Works as expected

sort_func(data = mtcars, by_vars = as.vector(cyl, hp)) ## Returns error "Problem with implicit transmute"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution that does something similar.

```
sort_func <- function(data, by_vars){
               var <- rlang::parse_exprs(by_vars)
               ds <- data %>% dplyr::arrange(!!!var)
               return(ds)
               }

sort_func(data = mtcars, by_vars = "cyl;desc(hp)")
```

Here the variables have to be entered as a string separated, with each variable separated by ; or \n.